# Match escape sequence for "bold" in console output with grep

Tags: command-line, grep, bold

Hi I have lots of logfiles with ^[[1m (as vim displays it) in them. I want to watch a logfile life via

```
tail -n 1000 -f logfile.log | grep <expression-for-escape-sequence>
```

and only get lines that have bold in them.
I am not sure which grep options I should use and have tried the following already:

```
tail -n 1000 -f logfile.log | grep "\033\0133\061\0155"
tail -n 1000 -f logfile.log | grep "\033\01331m"
tail -n 1000 -f logfile.log | grep "\033\[1m"
```

It does not work though... And yes there are bold lines in the last 1000 lines of logfile.log, testing with

```
echo -e "\033\01331mTest\033\01330m" | grep ...
```

same results... ;)

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2):

Use single quotes with a dollar sign in front—as in `$'...'`—to have the shell convert the `\033` escape sequence into an ESC character:

```
tail -n 1000 -f logfile.log | grep $'\033\[1m'
```

From **man bash**:

> Words  of  the  form  `$'string'` are treated specially.  The word expands to `string`, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.

Comment: Thanks! this is exactly what I was looking for! It was really a nightmare searching google for a solution because of all the special characters ;) !

Answer (score 0):

This works (in a POSIX shell, not necessarily bash):

```
echo -e "\033\01331mTest\033\01330m" | grep "$(printf "\x1b\\[1m")"
```